# Confidence interval for mean of highly skewed distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, skewness

My background: I have completed an introductory course in statistics and done some further reading on my own. I have 3 months of R experience.

I have been asked to design an experiment to measure the effect of removing ads on user spending and retention in a mobile game.

The main criterion is to keep the test group small to minimize the amount of revenue at risk.

For retention (measured as percent retained for a given day), I chose a level of confidence I wanted, and used the Clopper-Pearson method to find the necessary test group size, which was not prohibitively big.

For spending, however, the distribution is exponential, with a long tail of outrageously big spenders, making the test group size needed to get enough accuracy prohibitively large.

Has anybody run into this problem before? Are there any design techniques or stats tricks I can use to get the desired accuracy? I suspect there might a better confidence interval I than the standard CI for a continuous variable, which I am using. I read that bootstrapping can increase accuracy, but I don't really understand how it works.

Comment: The mean of a highly skewed distribution is unstable, which explains your large sample size. Maybe you could reformulate the research hypothesis using the median or some other quantile?